# componentDidMount() : call function after getItem from asyncStorage

Tags: react-native

I have to send an codeActivation with my API after calling this codeActivation from asyncStorage so I use this code:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    AsyncStorage.getItem(CODEACTIVATION_STORED)
        .then(code => {
            this.setState({ codeActivation: code})
            console.log('t2 ' + this.state.codeActivation); << output : t1 544875962

    });
    AsyncStorage.getItem(TOKEN_STORED)
        .then(code => {
            this.setState({ Token: code})
    });
    console.log('t1 ' + this.state.codeActivation); << output: t1 
      this.pwHash(); << where I use this.state.codeActivation

  }
```

how to call pwHash after setting my codeActivation from asyncStorage in this.state.codeActivation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(() => {
      AsyncStorage.getItem(CODEACTIVATION_STORED)
        .then(code => {
            this.setState({ codeActivation: code})
            console.log('t2 ' + this.state.codeActivation); << output : t1 544875962



    });
    AsyncStorage.getItem(TOKEN_STORED)
        .then(code => {
            this.setState({ Token: code})
      console.log('t1 ' + this.state.codeActivation); << output: t1 
      this.pwHash(); << where I use this.state.codeActivation && this.state.token
    });
    }, 5000);
  }
```

you can call it like this or you can just ignore `setInterval()` if that is not you need.

Comment: I need Token to, I have to set token and codeActivation not only codeActivation

Comment: I used setTimeout instead but only on this.pwHash . Thank you man

Comment: I updated the code as well where you can use this.pwHash